# Problema para graficar dentro de un JPanel

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing

Tengo un problema, quiero meter un grafico que hice en un jframe en un jpanel dentro de ese jframe. Estoy trabajando en Netbeans. ¿Alguien lo puede solucionar? El grafico que hice fue importando esta clase para dibujar una funcion de perlin noise:
https://github.com/warmwaffles/Noise/blob/master/src/noisy/Noisy.java

Para el grafico use esto, primero dentro de mi jframe, y ahora lo quiero trasladar al jpanel que va a tener adentro:

```
Noisy noisy = new Noisy((int) (100000 * Math.random()), 3);

public void paint(Graphics g) {

        int y1, y2 = 0, x1, x2 = 0;
        float rugosidad = 0.1f;

        for (int i = 0; i < (500 * rugosidad); i++) {

            y1 = (int) (100 * (noisy.perlinNoise((float) i / 10) + 1));
            x1 = (int) (i / rugosidad);

            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);

            y2 = y1;
            x2 = x1;

        }

}
```

**Por favor, necesito su ayuda.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El componente `JPanel` solo necesitaria sobre-escribir su método `paint` o `paintComponent` de la misma manera que lo hace el contenedor del `JFrame`.

Algo como lo siguiente puede ser una buena aproximación:

```
//...

miPanel = new JPanel() {
  Noisy noisy = new Noisy((int) (100000 * Math.random()), 3);

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    int y1, y2 = 0, x1, x2 = 0;
    float rugosidad = 0.1f;

    for (int i = 0; i < (500 * rugosidad); i++) {
      y1 = (int) (100 * (noisy.perlinNoise((float) i / 10) + 1));
      x1 = (int) (i / rugosidad);

      g.setColor(Color.red);
      g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);

      y2 = y1;
      x2 = x1;
    }
  }
};
getContentPane().add(miPanel);//u otra manera alternativa de agregar componentes

//...
```

Por ejemplo, en un `JPanel` con `LineBorder`, se obtuvo esta captura:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias, se que parezco tonto preguntando esto pero donde coloco ese codigo? ¿En el jframe, en el "Custom code" que sale cuando hago click derecho en un jpanel que puse dentro, o en una nueva clase que extienda jpanel?¿Y en que parte?¿Dentro de public Ventana() {} si Ventana extiende JFrame?

Comment: Disculpa la gran demora.... el ejemplo de arriba originalmente esta dentro del constructor de un `JFrame`; También, y en mi preferencia, puedes crear una clase aparte que extienda de `JPanel` y pegar ese código que suministraste en la pregunta.

Comment: Para todos aquellos dudosos, aquí está la solución más completa: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/215794/qu%c3%a9-debo-hacer-para-dibujar-una-l%c3%adnea-dentro-de-un-jpanel-dentro-de-un-jframe-e